# PLEASE help me get armoury to online on my mac?

Tags: mac, armory, bitcoin-qt-setup

Macos 10.11.6 El Capitan
Armoury 0.93.3
BitcoinQT v0.17.1

I have to use those software versions to get them to open in OS10.11

I cannot get armoury to go online. PLEASE HELP ME.

Both apps open separately.

I type this '/Applications/Armory.app/Contents/MacOS/Armory' into terminal and got this.
(ERROR) ArmoryQt.py:7074 - Socket already in use.  Sending CLI args to existing proc.
(ERROR) ArmoryQt.py:7078 - Exiting...

I'm not sure if this is the only issue or how to fix it?

Comment: Are you trying to set up a new wallet, or restore an old one? Armory has been out of vogue for a long time, it is very slow and has very little development.

Comment: Are you sure you can't use Armory's latest version? Backwards compatibility is a top priority in wallet development.